# SQLSRV Fatal error: Severe error translating Unicode

Tags: php, sql-server, unicode, while-loop

I'm trying to run a basic while loop in PHP for an SQL Sever database. I get back the following error:

```
Fatal error: Severe error translating Unicode
```

The code works on another script so I think it's something to do with the table I'm querying. This is the code I'm using

```
if(isset($_GET['uid']) && $_GET['uid'] != ''){
$uid = $_GET['uid'];
// check for user
$staffSQL = "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE userid = '".$uid."'";
$params = array();
$staff = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $staffSQL, $params, array("Scrollable"=>"buffered"));

$numStaff = sqlsrv_num_rows($staff);

if($numStaff  < 1){
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "No projects found!";
}else{
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $staff, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        foreach($row as $key => $value) {
            echo "$key = $value <br />";
        }
    }
}
```

After some Googling I found [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/62b6f339-46f4-4ae9-acd6-0346a4c2cacf/severe-error-translating-unicode-when-calling-sqlsrvfetcharray-on-a-query-with-buffered-cursor?forum=sqldriverforphp) but the suggested code there return nothing but incomprehensible giberish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so after some more Googling I found [this page](http://www.johnro.net/2012/07/25/php-sqlsrv-problems-with-utf-8-values-set-your-characterset-option/) which says that the solution is adding a CharacterSet option within the sqlsrv_connect function.

```
$result = sqlsrv_connect($hostname, array(
    'UID' => $username,
    'PWD' => $password,
    'Database' => $database,
    'ConnectionPooling' => ($pooling) ? 1 : 0,
    "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"       // <---- voila
));
```

I have tested this and it works perfectly.